# Is $x^k$ in a polynomial subspace $\mathcal{P}_n$ where $n>k$?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

So I'm pretty confused about polynomial subspaces. Say I have a polynomial $ p(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4 $, whose highest degree is 3, would this be in $\mathcal{P}_4$? I have been reading other answers on this site saying that since the largest degree in $ x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4 $ is 3, it is not in $\mathcal{P}_4$, however, my teacher has told me that any polynomial of a degree smaller than the subspace in question is in fact in that subspace because the coefficient in front of the largest degree could be 0, for example

$ p(x) = x^3 $ is in $\mathcal{P}_5$ because $ p(x) $ could be $ x^3 + 0x^4 + 0x^5 $.

From answers on here, for example, proving that $\mathcal{P}_n$ is not a subspace:

Let $ p(x) = x^3 + x^2 $ and $ q(x) = -x^3 + x^2$, then $ p(x) + q(x) = 2x^2$ which is not of degree 3, therefore it is not $\mathcal{P}_n$ as it is not closed under addition. But couldn't you express $ p(x) + q(x) $ as $ 2x^2 + 0x^3 $?

Could I get some clarification on this? Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on how **exactly** you define $\mathcal{P}_n$. The $\mathcal{P}_n$ symbol is not standard. So it can be $\mathcal{P}_n=\{f\in k[X]\ |\ \deg f=n\}$. Or maybe $\mathcal{P}_n=\{f\in k[X]\ |\ \deg f\leq n\}$? We can't know that, but you should know that. Once you read the definition it will most likely become clear.

Comment: Hi @sk2000. Yes it is possible for a polynomial with degree less than n be in Pn (lazy notation sorry). And a straightforward reason of why is that possible, is because one basis for Pn is 1,x,x^2,....,x^n. (Yes 1 is a possible vector in the basis of Pn). So as you said, the coefficient in front of a vector can equal zero when taking a linear combination of the vectors in the basis of Pn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal P_n$ is the space of polynomials with degree $\leq n$. Otherwise it would not be a vector space. The reason is that you can take a polynomial $f=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ and subtract the polynomial $X^n$ to get

$$a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=f-X^n,$$

which has to be in $\mathcal P_n$ for it to be a vector space. You can construct polynomials of lower degree in a similar way to find that a vector space containing all polynomials of degree $n$ must also contain all polynomials of lower degree than $n$. Also keep in mind that while you can express a polynomial as $2X^2$ or as $0X^3+2X^2$, taking that to mean that the degree depends on how we write it down really defeats the purpose of defining a degree. The degree of a polynomial is the highest exponent of $X$ with *non-zero* coefficient.

Of course, you could define $\mathcal P_n$ differently if you're not interested in it being a vector space, but I've only seen this notation for vector spaces of polynomials.

Comment: Your point about $ \mathcal{P}_n $ being the space of polynomials with degree $  \leq n $ cleared things up! So if, for example, I was to find a polynomial $ p(x) $ in $ \mathcal{P}_5 $ such that $ p(2) = 2$, could I just say $ p(x) = x $?

Comment: Yes, you could, if there are no other restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{P}_{n}$ is vector space of dimension $(n+1)$ over any field $\mathbb{F}$ with the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x^n\}$.

That means, any polynomial $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_0$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ are the elements of the vector space $\mathcal{P}_{n}$.

So, any polynomial of degree $\le n $ over $\mathbb{F}$  belong into $\mathcal{P}_{n}$.